# Narration in Robert Barr's In the Midst of Alarms: omniscient, third-person limited or something else?

Tags: narrator, robert-barr, in-the-midst-of-alarms

In a [comment on an answer about Robert Barr's novel *In the Midst of Alarms*](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/17341/whats-the-significance-of-at-least-here/17342?noredirect=1#comment26973_17342) Gareth Rees wrote,

> The narration is third-person *limited*, that is, we are getting the events largely from Yates' point of view, so I interpret "Perhaps this was because she had been taken so completely by surprise" as representing Yates' own interpretation of what happened. An omniscient narrator would not need to use the word "perhaps".

I [responded](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/17341/whats-the-significance-of-at-least-here/17342?noredirect=1#comment26978_17342) by asking,

> If you regard the narration as third-person limited, do you mean a narrator who follows Yates's perspective? If yes, how does that explain that this narrator knows what Professor Renmark feels in the book's [first chapter](http://www.fullbooks.com/In-the-Midst-of-Alarms1.html)?

The discussion did not continue but seems worth a question of its own. So what is the narrative point of view in Robert Barr's novel: omniscient, third-person limited or something else?